# CouchDB - Preferred structure for access/event logging

Tags: couchdb

I'm just getting started with CouchDB and looking for some best practices. My current project is a CMS/Wiki-like tool that contains many pages of content. So far, this seems to fit well with CouchDB. The next thing I want to do is track every time a page on the site is accessed.

Each access log should contain the timestamp, the URI of the page that was accessed and the UUID of the user who accessed it. How is the best way to structure this access log information in CouchDB? It's likely that any given page will be accessed up to 100 times per day.

A couple thoughts I've had so far:

1. 1 CouchDB document per page that contains ALL access logs.
2. 1 CouchDB document per log.

If it's one document per log, should all the logs be in their own CouchDB database to keep the main DB cleaner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not 1st option. Because CouchDb is an append only storage, each time you update document, new document with same ID but different revision is created. And if you have 100 hits for a page in a day 100 new documents will be created, as a result you database will quickly get huge. So its better to use your second option.

As for the separate database for logs, it depends on your data and how you plan to use it. You can create separate view just for your logs if you decide to keep all your data in same place.